# How do I instruct ARM cortext to do tail chaining of interrupts or stack pop pre-emption?

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, microcontroller

Is there any special mode or registers I need to set so that the ARM processor having NVIC uses tail chaining and stack pop pre-emption of interrupts.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no special mode. Providing you have interrupts enabled with the right priorities, the core will preempt (requiring a higher priority arrival during stacking), or tail-chain (same or lower priority) whenever a 2nd interrupt arrives after the first has started to be handled.

There is no gain to be had from disabling this behaviour, the priority registers already give you full control.